# Hibernate querying on fields that do not exist in table anymore

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, jpa

I have an entity that has a many to one mapping to another entity.
Here is the mapping:

```
@JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
 @ManyToOne 
private User user;
```

In the object (and table) user I used to have a field called authorityId. I removed that field from the table and the object.
Now, when I user `find()` on the object Hibernate generates a query including the old fields and not including new fields that I have added to the table (and mapped in the object).

Please note that this does not happen all the time, most of the time the query runs fine but every once and a while I get the exception `MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column`.

I cannot find a reason for this, any ideas?

the find I use is the `find(Long id)` of theJPA: `entry = auditLogDAO.find(id);`

The code of the User object:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User implements Serializable{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name="id",unique=true, nullable=false )
    @GeneratedValue( strategy = IDENTITY )
    private Long id;

    @Column(name ="username",unique=true, nullable=false)
    @Field(index = Index.TOKENIZED, store = Store.NO)
    private String username;

    @Column
    private String password;

    @Column
    private int enabled;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "current_account", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Account currentAccount;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "original_account", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Account originalAccount;

    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private List<Authority> authorities;

    @Column(name="first_name")
    @Field(index = Index.TOKENIZED, store = Store.NO)
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name="last_name")
    @Field(index = Index.TOKENIZED, store = Store.NO)
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name="email",unique=true, nullable=false )
    @Field(index = Index.TOKENIZED, store = Store.NO)
    private String email;

    @Column(name="switch_allowed")
    private Boolean switchAllowed;

    @Lob
    @Column(name = "additional_emails")
    private String additionalEmails;
```

The Authority table:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "authorities")
public class Authority implements Serializable{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue( strategy = IDENTITY )
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "user_id")
    private Long userId;

    @Column(name = "authority")
    private String authority;
```

Full stack trace (if you can see, in the query generated by hibernate there is user6_.authority_id, a column that does not exist anymore in the mapping):

> org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException:
>   could not load an entity:
>   [com.legolas.model.AuditLog#3048]; SQL
>   [select auditlog0_.id as id26_8_,
>   auditlog0_.account_id as
>   account8_26_8_, auditlog0_.date as
>   date26_8_, auditlog0_.domain_object_id
>   as domain3_26_8_,
>   auditlog0_.event_type as event4_26_8_,
>   auditlog0_.notified as notified26_8_,
>   auditlog0_.object_type as
>   object6_26_8_, auditlog0_.object_xml
>   as object7_26_8_, auditlog0_.user_id
>   as user9_26_8_, account1_.id as
>   id7_0_, account1_.account_type as
>   account2_7_0_, account1_.name as
>   name7_0_, account1_1_.adserver_id as
>   adserver3_8_0_,
>   account1_1_.stamping_method as
>   stamping1_8_0_,
>   account1_3_.advertiser_id as
>   advertiser2_30_0_,
>   account1_4_.brand_id as brand2_54_0_,
>   account1_5_.in_use as in1_58_0_,
>   account1_5_.order_by as order2_58_0_,
>   account1_6_.agency_id as
>   agency2_60_0_, case when
>   account1_1_.account_id is not null
>   then 1 when account1_2_.account_id is
>   not null then 2 when
>   account1_3_.account_id is not null
>   then 3 when account1_4_.account_id is
>   not null then 4 when
>   account1_5_.account_id is not null
>   then 5 when account1_6_.account_id is
>   not null then 6 when account1_.id is
>   not null then 0 end as clazz_0_,
>   adserver2_.id as id0_1_,
>   adserver2_.name as name0_1_, case when
>   adserver2_1_.adserver_id is not null
>   then 1 when adserver2_2_.adserver_id
>   is not null then 2 when adserver2_.id
>   is not null then 0 end as clazz_1_,
>   advertiser3_.account_id as id7_2_,
>   advertiser3_1_.account_type as
>   account2_7_2_, advertiser3_1_.name as
>   name7_2_, advertiser3_.agency_id as
>   agency2_60_2_, brand4_.account_id as
>   id7_3_, brand4_1_.account_type as
>   account2_7_3_, brand4_1_.name as
>   name7_3_, brand4_.advertiser_id as
>   advertiser2_30_3_, agency5_.account_id
>   as id7_4_, agency5_1_.account_type as
>   account2_7_4_, agency5_1_.name as
>   name7_4_, user6_.id as id6_5_,
>   user6_.additional_emails as
>   additional2_6_5_, user6_.authority_id
>   as authority10_6_5_, user6_.email as
>   email6_5_, user6_.enabled as
>   enabled6_5_, user6_.first_name as
>   first5_6_5_, user6_.last_name as
>   last6_6_5_, user6_.original_authority
>   as original11_6_5_, user6_.password as
>   password6_5_, user6_.switch_allowed as
>   switch8_6_5_, user6_.username as
>   username6_5_, authority7_.id as
>   id5_6_, authority7_.account_id as
>   account2_5_6_, authority7_.authority
>   as authority5_6_, authority7_.username
>   as username5_6_, authority8_.id as
>   id5_7_, authority8_.account_id as
>   account2_5_7_, authority8_.authority
>   as authority5_7_, authority8_.username
>   as username5_7_ from audit_log
>   auditlog0_ left outer join accounts
>   account1_ on
>   auditlog0_.account_id=account1_.id
>   left outer join publishers account1_1_
>   on account1_.id=account1_1_.account_id
>   left outer join agencies account1_2_
>   on account1_.id=account1_2_.account_id
>   left outer join brands account1_3_ on
>   account1_.id=account1_3_.account_id
>   left outer join products account1_4_
>   on account1_.id=account1_4_.account_id
>   left outer join data_vendors
>   account1_5_ on
>   account1_.id=account1_5_.account_id
>   left outer join advertisers
>   account1_6_ on
>   account1_.id=account1_6_.account_id
>   left outer join adservers adserver2_
>   on
>   account1_1_.adserver_id=adserver2_.id
>   left outer join ad_server_agency
>   adserver2_1_ on
>   adserver2_.id=adserver2_1_.adserver_id
>   left outer join ad_server_publisher
>   adserver2_2_ on
>   adserver2_.id=adserver2_2_.adserver_id
>   left outer join advertisers
>   advertiser3_ on
>   account1_3_.advertiser_id=advertiser3_.account_id
>   left outer join accounts
>   advertiser3_1_ on
>   advertiser3_.account_id=advertiser3_1_.id
>   left outer join brands brand4_ on
>   account1_4_.brand_id=brand4_.account_id
>   left outer join accounts brand4_1_ on
>   brand4_.account_id=brand4_1_.id left
>   outer join agencies agency5_ on
>   account1_6_.agency_id=agency5_.account_id
>   left outer join accounts agency5_1_ on
>   agency5_.account_id=agency5_1_.id left
>   outer join users user6_ on
>   auditlog0_.user_id=user6_.id left
>   outer join authorities authority7_ on
>   user6_.authority_id=authority7_.id
>   left outer join authorities
>   authority8_ on
>   user6_.original_authority=authority8_.id
>   where auditlog0_.id=?]; nested
>   exception is
>   org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException:
>   could not load an entity:
>   [com.legolas.model.AuditLog#3048]     at
>   org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SessionFactoryUtils.convertHibernateAccessException(SessionFactoryUtils.java:629)
>     at
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:100)
>     at
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:368)
>     at
>   org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:58)
>     at
>   org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:213)
>     at
>   org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:163)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
>     at
>   org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:89)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
>     at $Proxy317.find(Unknown Source)   at
>   com.legolas.notifications.jobs.NotificationJob.asapNotification(NotificationJob.java:133)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
>   Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
>     at
>   org.springframework.util.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:273)
>     at
>   org.springframework.scheduling.support.MethodInvokingRunnable.run(MethodInvokingRunnable.java:65)
>     at
>   org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:51)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRunAndReset(FutureTask.java:351)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:178)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:165)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:267)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
>     at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:636)
>   Caused by:
>   org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException:
>   could not load an entity:
>   [com.legolas.model.AuditLog#3048]     at
>   org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:92)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadEntity(Loader.java:1957)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:86)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:76)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.load(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3270)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromDatasource(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:496)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:477)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:227)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:285)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:152)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:1080)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.get(SessionImpl.java:997)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.get(SessionImpl.java:990)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.find(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:554)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.find(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:529)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
>   Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
>     at
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:240)
>     at $Proxy236.find(Unknown Source)   at
>   com.legolas.dao.GenericDAOWithJPA.find(GenericDAOWithJPA.java:55)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
>   Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:309)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
>     at
>   org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:155)
>     ... 23 more Caused by:
>   com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException:
>   Unknown column 'user6_.authority_id'
>   in 'field list'   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native
>   Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:532)
>     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:406)
>     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:381)
>     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1030)
>     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:956)
>     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3491)
>     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3423)
>     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1936)
>     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2060)
>     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2542)
>     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1734)
>     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:1885)
>     at
>   org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:93)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.getResultSet(AbstractBatcher.java:208)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:1869)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:718)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:270)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadEntity(Loader.java:1953)
>     ... 51 more

Comment: @anergy yes, i assume you mean the application jar

Comment: elaborate on find(). How do you find(). Could you post you code?

Comment: @joostschouten - code posted above

Comment: Ok, it's not the find(). Especially since it is not consistent you should provide the full stacktrace as well.

Comment: @joostschouten - stack trace above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you still have your Authority (authorities table) mapped which has a relationship with your User. This will most likely map to authority_id causing your problem. Either fix the Authority mapping or remove it completely. If this is not the case you will have a classloading problem loading an older version of your model.

Comment: I posted the authorities tables above, I dont think that this is the issue. If there is a class loading problem - how can I detect it?

Comment: That all depends on your runtime environment. One way to be sure is to completely delete all your compiled code, rebuild your entire app (maven/ant/grails whatever you use) and setup a new runtime environment (eg. tomcat/jetty for webapps) and run your app from the commandline and not from your IDE.

Comment: I always build my app from scratch (Maven clean install), ill try your other suggestions

Comment: sometimes it's a good idea to clean your local repo as well.  ~/.m2/repository/

Comment: Clean my repository and built my app from scratch, and still i get this error from time to time...

Comment: It's the "from time to time" that you should focus on. Try to create a scenario where you get this exception all the time. Use debuggers in your catch block to figure out what the circumstances are. Inconsistency is your enemy :)

Comment: you are right, I will accept this answer but Ill continue to try and find it :)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem: I deleted a column from one of my database tables, changed all the Java/Hibernate code so that it no longer referred to that column, but still got this error at runtime.

In my case, the problem had to do with a dependent project. That is, the Java code was in a separate project, on which my main project depended. To make Eclipse and Tomcat acknowledge the changes in the dependent project, I did two things in the main project.

1. Properties | Java Build Path | Projects. Remove the dependent project. Close the dialog box. Return to Properties | Java Build Path | Projects and re-add the dependent project.
2. Properties | Deployment Assembly | Projects. Remove the dependent project. Close the dialog box. Return to Properties | Assembly | Projects and re-add the dependent project.

Then restart the Tomcat server.